# How to test debug_backtrace results?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

### Summary

I have a class that uses `debug_backtrace()` for reporting where a method was called. The method may be called in third party code either directly or via some helper method that's in the same package as the class in question. In the latter case the method will report the line from the third party code and not from the helper class, thus the index at which the actual caller is in the results varies, so I'd like to include a test in my PHPUnit suite which would ensure that the correct index is found in each use case.

Is there a way I could automatically and reliably figure out the correct line in the test file that my method should return?

---

### tl;dr, code plz

Here's some code to demonstrate. This is just the most bare bones example of the situation, please disregard that it doesn't really make sense. The actual use case is more complex and it's very much possible, likely even, that at some point in time I will mess something up and the traces end up giving wrong results. I'd like my tests to catch that.

Classes.php:

```
<?php

class Tracer
{
    public function send()
    {
        $trace = debug_backtrace();

        if ($trace[1]['class'] === 'Helper') {
            $calledOnLine = $trace[2]['line'];
        } else {
            $calledOnLine = $trace[1]['line'];
        }

        return $calledOnLine;
    }
}

class Helper
{
    public static function send()
    {
        $Tracer = new Tracer;
        return $tracer->send();
    }
}
```

TracerTest.php:

```
<?php

class TracerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testGetProperCallerInfo()
    {
        $Tracer = new Tracer;

        $result1 = $Tracer->send();  // $TargetLine1
        $result2 = Helper::send();   // $TargetLine2

        $this->assertEquals($TargetLine1, $result1);
        $this->assertEquals($TargetLine2, $result2);
    }

}
```

---

### Ideas

I could hardcode the line numbers into the test, and then update them each and every time something higher up in the test file changes. Even if I separate this particular test to its own file it's still going to break at some point, and besides it's such an ugly solution I wouldn't be able to look myself in the eye anymore.

Another method might be to tag the target lines with comments, load the test file to an array with `file()` and find the tags in the array. This is still somewhat fragile, and not really all that elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself, what is the behavior you are trying to test?

If you want to ensure you are generating exact strings, then maybe test fixtures is a good idea.

Probably more easier to maintain is to assert parts of the string which can be easily inferred.

Alternatively, you can mock the function call itself with libraries such as

1. https://github.com/instaclick/ICBaseTestBundle/blob/master/Test/Helper/Unit/FunctionHelper.php
2. http://www.workhabit.com/labs/mock-function-testing-drupal

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I could mock `debug_backtrace()` to produce a predetermined result, but then my test should always know how many internal calls there are in the trace, and this would invalidate my tests if the internal flow ever changes, regardless of whether the results are still correct or not. I think the 'tag&search' I mentioned would be more robust. As for the string generation part, I don't think I get what you're suggesting, as I'm not generating or even comparing any strings, but line numbers. Could you go over that bit again?

Answer (score 0):

Since I haven't been able to find a better solution, I ended up putting together a small package that let's me find lines reliably from the test source.

Accepted answer is still up for grabs if you can come up with a better solution!

In case someone is interested, the package I made is [here](https://github.com/schlaus/Tagline).